# How To Fix Apache malformed header from script 'index.php': Bad header: Register In Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, apache, xampp, httpd.conf

How To Fix Apache malformed header from script 'index.php': Bad header: Register In Laravel 5.6

Run In Apache 2.4.29 (CenOS 7)

Code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmsFI.png)

Result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1vSX.png)

Log Apache error_log Show 
==>>  [Sat Apr 21 22:04:03.967658 2018] [core:error] [pid 18494:tid 139869258323712] [client 27.55.71.124:57216] malformed header from script 'index.php': Bad header: Register Repositories

But Run In Xampp (Local) Run Success

Thank You

Comment: Please include code in the question itself, not as an image ([ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `ConsoleOutput::writeln` writes to the `stdout` but the headers would not work for a web server, so this doesn't makes sense.

Instead, you should be checking if your application is running in the console when executing this portion of code:

```
if(app()->runningInConsole()) {
    ConsoleOuput::writeln('Register Repositories');
}
```